# Difference between Java generics syntax?

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

What is the difference between these method definitions?

```
public <T extends Foo> void loadData(Class<T> p_class);

public void loadData(Class<? extends Foo> p_class);
```

Comment: In the second form, you won't be able to refer to **T** inside method

Comment: I cannot think of a practical thing that only one approach would let you do, and the other one would prohibit.

Comment: @Vyncent: Inside *that* specific method, but it can just call through to a capture helper which can use `T` inside it. To outside code, there is nothing that one can do that the other can't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both signatures accept exactly the same set of arguments, so in that sense are equivalent. As pointed out in the comments, in the second case you will not be able to refer to `T` in the body of the method. However, according to Effective Java, the second signature is preferred (as it is shorter and slightly clearer). In that book, the advice given is to use the second signature, and use a private helper method with the first signature if `T` is required in the method. Like this:

```
private <T extends Foo> void helper(Class<T> p_class) {
    // code
}

public void loadData(Class<? extends Foo> p_class) {
    helper(p_class);
}
```

Comment: So, both work the same but the second signature can do less in the body.
So that a second method using the first signature is needed. And yet Effective Java states the second one is shorter and preferred? To me it feels like the opposite is true, first signature needs only one method is clearly shorter and less confusing. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Diskutant It's less confusing to the caller of the method, not the person who writes it. It is more clear if there is more than one type parameter. I think `public <T, U, V extends Number> void foo(List<T> list, Map<U, V> map)` is more convoluted than `public void foo(List<?> list, Map<?, ? extends Number> map)`. In the second case it's completely obvious that the `List` can be of any type and the values of the `Map` must extend `Number`. In the first case, there are 3 confusing type parameters and you have to look in two places to see that the `extends Number` bit is about the map's values.

Comment: @Diskutant It's also about encapsulation. The fact that `T` is needed in the body of the method is an implementation detail that the caller of the method doesn't care about. All the caller of the method cares about is that the method works if they pass a `Class` object of some type extending `Foo`. They shouldn't have to use a different signature because of an implementation detail.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference in syntactic usage, as the second method has a generic type parameter.

```
class Bar extends Foo { }

obj.<Bar>loadData(klazz);
```

This requires klazz to be `Class<Bar>` exactly.